# How to get the facebook cover image after authenticating through loopback

Tags: facebook, authentication, passport.js, loopback, passport-facebook

I am integrating passport with loopback (Facebook Authentication), and works fine, the problems is how to get the cover image.

Now i got some facebook data like email,name,profile image like that.

I want the facebook cover photo.

Is it possible ?

**provider.son**

```
 "facebook-login":
 {
   "provider": "facebook",
   "module": "passport-facebook",
   "clientID": "*****************",
   "clientSecret": "*******************",
   "callbackURL": "https://localhost/auth/facebook/callback",
   "authPath": "/auth/facebook",
   "callbackPath": "/auth/facebook/callback",
   "successRedirect": "/auth/account",
   "failureRedirect": "/login",
   "scope": [
      "email",
      "public_profile"
    ],
   "profileFields": [
    "id",
    "email",
    "gender",
    "is_verified",
    "languages",
    "picture.type(large)",
    "name",
    "verified"
    ],
   "failureFlash": true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The API reference says that there is a `cover` field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

...but it seems to be deprecated with v3.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0

I assume it is not possible to get the cover image anymore.